# How/Where do you install Console2 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, console2

I downloaded the source and binaries from http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/

In the binaries help file it makes reference to a setup file but there is none.

The list of files included in the Console-2.00b145-Beta.zip is:

- Microsoft.VC90.CRT (folder)
- console.chm
- Console.exe
- console.xml
- ConsoleHook.dll
- FreeImage.dll
- FreeImagePlus.dll

How do I setup or place the files for Console2 on Windows 7?

Comment: which error you'd found when you run console.exe ? .dll not found ? take a look [here](http://looselytyped.com/2008/05/04/console2-a-worthy-cmd-window-replacement/). hope this helps.

Comment: no error. it just mentioned a setup file in the help chm and I didn't see it.

Comment: Consider using [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console). It is essentially a fork of the original Console2 project, which has become dormant. ConsoleZ is being actively developed, and provides a better experience under Windows 7/8.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's what I did

1. Download Console2 from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/console-devel/2.00/) (get _32bit.zip or _64bit.zip version depending on your OS)
2. Download Console2 src just to get the .ico file
3. Copy the Console2 folder to C:\Program Files
4. Copy Console.ico file from the Console Source downloads to the folder above
5. Open Console2 and edit your settings for font or better read [Scott
   Hanselman's blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx) on his Console2 setup

To add a Context Menu that will open Console2 on a specific directory update the registry as follows (Windows7):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\open_console]
@=Open Console2 Here
Icon=C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.ico

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\open_console\Command]
@=C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe -d "%v"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\open_console]
@=Open Console2 Here
Icon=C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.ico

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\open_console\Command]
@=C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe -d "%v"
```

The first registry entry for HKCR adds a "Open Console2 Here" context menu item when you are clicking ON a folder.

The second registry entry for HKLM adds a "Open Console2 Here" context menu item when you are in a folder and clicking the background.

Comment: any reason why you added the background keys to HKLM instead of HKCR

Comment: Yes. The first one adds a context menu to a Folder background and the second adds a context menu item "Open Console2 Here" to a Folder icon.

Comment: Actually, your comment is backwards. The first one adds a context menu entry to a folder icon and the second to a folder background. There is no reason why you can't put them both in HKCR or both in HKLM.

Comment: Also, I had to escape the values for the registry to accept them. e.g. `@="Open Console2 Here"` and `@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Console2\\Console.exe\" -d \"%V\""`

Comment: Do everything as Brian Boatright explained. If it doesn't work try `C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe -d %1` instead of `@=C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe -d "%v"`

Answer (score 4):

I have Console2 running on Windows 7 64bit and resolved it much easier.
While having the C drive for programs, I use the D drive for tools and other data.

**Installation Path:** `D:\Tools\Console2`

Now you just have to edit your system variable "PATH" and add the installation path to it:

**Key**: PATH

**Value**: {other paths}`;D:\Tools\Console2` (no semicolon required at the end)

Now you can just type "console" (since the file name is "console.exe") to the run command (Windows + R) and Console2 will start right away.

***Tip***: In combination with "Total Commander", you can just toggle the command bar. So when you place yourself on a specific path and just start typing "console" it will start Console2 with that specific path. That avoids thousands of "cd" commands to get where you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Chocolately](https://chocolatey.org/), perform its installation as stated on its homepage

```
 @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

Then

```
choco install consolez
```

after its installed, run

```
console
```